# Prevent implicit closure of a ScrollableResults on exit from a Grails service

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I have a Grails application thread (a Quartz job) that does batch processing of a large number of records. The processing creates a new object with a different object type  that is based on the input object. The new object refers to the input object. The input object is immutable and is not modified in any way.

I'm attempting to use a ScrollableResults obtained from the Grails criteria API to iterate the set of input objects efficiently. The outer iteration is done outside of a transaction because I want to calculate progress on the batch by counting the number of processed records that I have created. Each output record is created in a separate transaction.

After I successfully process the first input object retrieved from the ScrollableResults, I get the following exception when trying to fetch the second input object:

```
Message: could not advance using next()
   Line | Method
->> 107 | execute in com.spiekerpoint.reacs.ForecastJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   102 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
|   202 | run . . in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run     in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
->> 1086 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
```

The input object, and by extension the outer cursor (ScrollableResult), have joined the implicit transaction created by the Grails service call that does the processing for the new record and the cursor is implicitly closed.

Here are simplified versions of the classes and job code that are in play:

```
class InventoryItem {
    String name
}

class ForecastInventoryItem {
    InventoryItem item
    Long forecast
}

/**** Quartz Job Code ****/

//Create a cursor based query for satellite inventory items
Closure criteriaClosure = forecastService.queryInventoryItemsWithCursor(forecast)
ScrollableResults cursor = InventoryItem.createCriteria().scroll(criteriaClosure)

//Forecast the inventory items
while (cursor.next()) {

    //Get the next inventory item to forecast from the cursor
    InventoryItem inventoryItem = cursor.get()[0]
    if (!inventoryItem) {
        log.error("Failed to fetch inventory item from scrollable result.")
        return
    }

    //Forecast the item
    log.info("Forecasting inventory item ${inventoryItem}")
    forecastService.forecastInventoryItem(forecast, inventoryItem)
}
cursor.close()
```

I have tried the following things to "detach" the inventoryItem instance from the forecastService initiated transaction:

1. I wrapped the call to forecastService.forecastInventoryItem in a withNewTransaction {} block.
2. I passed in the inventoryItem id to the service within the new transaction and let it acquire a new copy of the InventoryItem record.

It still insists on closing the cursor on the close of the service transaction.

I could of course put everything into a single transaction but then I loose the benefit of being able to poll for progress on the processing because they won't show up to any thread (ie. the controllers) until the entire transaction closes.

Any thoughts from the Grails gurus on how I might be able to separate the outer cursor from the transaction and keep it from implicitly closing on return from the service call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the transaction boundary problem inside the Quartz job by avoiding loading and handling of any objects in the job execution handler. I did this by eliminating the cursor and changing the criteria search to use a projection that returns a list of ids for the matching InventoryItem records. I then added a set of ForecastService methods that accepted an id for the InventoryItem and then fetched the InventoryItem record in the method. I also added a service method to flush the Hibernate session cache periodically (every 30 transaction was optimal for this particular case) keeping my memory usage low and avoiding the thrashing that kills performance when doing batch processing in a Hibernate session.

The result was a performance increase from ~3 items per second to ~80 items per second. Also, because each forecast runs in its own transaction, I can asynchronously track the progress of the forecast process by counting the number of ForecastInventoryItem object relative to the number of target InventoryItems.

In summary, do not deal with any domain objects in the job execution method because they will communicate the transaction boundary into the job.